# Google PPC hugely different cost estimates

Tags: google-ads, marketing, ppc

I am new to Adwords, and have set up my first campaign.

With the keyword planning tool, it suggests that for a bidding price of ZAR 0.14 (about USD 0.01) I can get 70 clicks a day for the keywords "online yoga" and "online yoga classes" and crop up no 3 for paid ads for a total of R5 (about USD0.5).

[image]

Yet on the Campaigns tab, it says that to appear on the first page I need to pay about R6.50 per click for the same set of keywords?

What is the truth here, the price difference is huge. If I pay ZAR 0.14 can I expect to get around 70 clicks as claimed in the Keyword Planner, from what others tell me about Adword costs this seems very wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by: `crop up no 3`?

Comment: adno 3 from the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will still get clicks even if you don't appear on the first page.   The tool is correct -- you will still get some clicks if you bid low.

The estimate assumes that you will have an excellent quality score.  It is likely that your first ad won't get an excellent quality score.   As a result you will get fewer clicks than predicted at that price.

Comment: It seemed to me that Google displays the same few adds on every page?

Comment: Google orders ads randomly, weighted by bids.   If there are two bidders at $1 and $2, the more expensive one will come first much more often, but the less expensive one will come first sometimes.   Even if you don't bid to the first page, your ad will occasionally show up somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I ran a campaign and can confirm that the keyword planner is worse than useless, actual clicks costed between R3 to R6, and I only got 3 clicks in 12 hours.

The only way to get the truth is to run a campaign